# Полный путь до исполняемого файла процесса

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi

Предположим мне известен PID процесса, как мне получить путь вида `\Device\HarddiskVolumeX\...\application.exe` зная этот PID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добиться желаемого в Windows (без использования сторонних модулей) можно несколькими способами, идеологически правильным из которых считается использование функции [QueryFullProcessImageName](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-queryfullprocessimagenamea). Последняя является оберткой над NTAPI'шной функцией `NtQueryInformationProcess`. Помимо прочего можно воспользоваться услугами `NtQuerySystemInformation`. Если облачить всё вышесказанное в код "на коленке":

```
from ctypes import (
   POINTER, Structure, addressof, byref, cast, create_unicode_buffer, c_long,
   c_ulong, c_ushort, c_void_p, c_wchar_p, sizeof, windll
)

ProcessImageFileName       = 27
SystemProcessIdInformation = 88
# пример "на коленке", так что restype и argtypes не заданы
CloseHandle               = windll.kernel32.CloseHandle
OpenProcess               = windll.kernel32.OpenProcess
NtQueryInformationProcess = windll.ntdll.NtQueryInformationProcess
NtQuerySystemInformation  = windll.ntdll.NtQuerySystemInformation
QueryFullProcessImageName = windll.kernel32.QueryFullProcessImageNameW

class UNICODE_STRING(Structure):
   _fields_ = (
      ('Length', c_ushort),
      ('MaximumLength', c_ushort),
      ('Buffer', c_wchar_p),
   )

class SYSTEM_PROCESS_ID_INFORMATION(Structure):
   _fields_ = (
      ('ProcessId', c_void_p),
      ('ImageName', UNICODE_STRING),
   )

def getexepath_1(pid):
   buf  = create_unicode_buffer(0x100)
   spii = SYSTEM_PROCESS_ID_INFORMATION()
   spii.ProcessId = c_void_p(pid)
   spii.ImageName.MaximumLength = len(buf)
   spii.ImageName.Buffer = addressof(buf)
   nts  = NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessIdInformation, spii, sizeof(spii), None)
   return buf.value if 0 == nts else 'n/a'

def getexepath_2(hndl):
   buf = create_unicode_buffer(0x100)
   req = c_ulong(len(buf))
   return buf.value if QueryFullProcessImageName(hndl, 1, buf, byref(req)) else 'n/a'

def getexepath_3(hndl):
   req = c_ulong()
   nts = NtQueryInformationProcess(hndl, ProcessImageFileName, None, None, byref(req))
   if c_long(0xC0000004).value != nts:
      return 'n/a'
   buf = create_unicode_buffer(req.value)
   nts = NtQueryInformationProcess(hndl, ProcessImageFileName, buf, len(buf), None)
   if 0 != nts:
      return 'n/a'
   return cast(buf, POINTER(UNICODE_STRING)).contents.Buffer

if __name__ == '__main__':
   print(getexepath_1(2032)) # какой-нибудь Id
   hndl = None
   try:
      hndl = OpenProcess(0x1000, False, 2032)
      print(getexepath_2(hndl))
      print(getexepath_3(hndl))
   except Exception as e:
      print(e)
   finally:
      if not CloseHandle(hndl):
         print('Опаньки!')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import psutil
for proc in psutil.process_iter ():
    try:
        if proc.pid == 1560:
            print (f'{proc.exe ()}')
    except psutil.AccessDenied:
        print ('(You do not have access to this process)')
```

примерно так, взял фрагмент кода с буржуйского сайта
UPD: поправил код - проверил - показывает полный путь

Comment: `cwd()` возвращает путь до текущей директории, а не исполняемого файла. И на всякий случай - гораздо эффективнее сделать `psutil.Process(PID).method() # получить процесс по PID`, тоже самое получение процесса (как у вас в цикле), но эффективнее

Answer (score 0):

```
import psutil

print(psutil.Process(PID).exe())
```

Создаётся объект класса `Process` на основе *PID*, далее с помощью метода `exe()` можно получить его исполняемый файл.